# Finding a concave function that minimize the middle value while the boundary values are fixed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

This question came to me while I was listening to Dominik's talk this afternoon. First, let me remind you what does f is concave mean. It means f satisfies $pf(x)+(1-p)f(y)\le 
f(px+(1-p)y)$, $\forall p\in [0,1]$.

The question is as follows: Given $n$, in a family of concave function $f:V\to R $, where $V$ is a set of vectors $(p_1,p_2,...,p_{2n})$ where $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_{2n}$ is in $[0,1]$ and $p_1+p_2+...+p_{2n}=1$, and f satisfies $f(p_1,p_2,...,p_{2n})= 1$ if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1$ or $\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n}p_i=1$. The objective is to find $argmin_f f(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n},...,\frac{1}{2n})$.

One candidate for the optimal $f$ is $f=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} p_i^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n} p_ip_j+\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{2n} p_ip_j=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}p_i)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n}p_i)^2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} p_i^2$. For this $f$, $f(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n},...,\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2n}$. I'm wondering if this is the solution or there's a better choice.

Comment: Title says "maximize the middle value" but text of Question asks to  find $argmin_f f(1/2n,1/2n,\ldots,1/2n)$, i.e. a minimization.  I'd guess you intend the latter (and that 1/2n means $(2n)^{-1}$), but it could stand clarification.

Comment: @hardmath:corrected, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be arbitrary and satisfies your assumptions. Hence, we have
$$f(1/n,\ldots,1/n,0,\ldots,0) = 1$$
and
$$f(0,\ldots,0,1/n,\ldots,1/n) = 1.$$
By concavity of $f$, this implies
$$f(1/(2n),\ldots,1/(2n)) \ge 1.$$

Finally, note that for the constant function $f \equiv 1$, this estimate is sharp. Hence, $1$ is the optimal value.

Moreover, this also shows that your function does not satisfy the requirements.

Comment: I think the condition is not exactly "concave function" which I'll check with Dominik. I would appreciate it if you can find some "concave-like" properties of the candidate function I gave, like concave for only a certain class of endpoints.